# Unsupported compiler 'com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42' xcode 5 DP

Tags: ios, xcode5, projects-and-solutions, llvm-gcc, geos

I have a project which contains Geos and Proj inside it. Before Xcode 5 I compiled them with LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler, but in Xcode 5 DP I get an error about unsupported compiler. Choosing another compiler get to compilation errors depends on syntax. How can I fix this trouble?

Answer (score -23, accepted):

A) Stop using Xcode 5

or

B) Fix the errors in your code

I know you won't like that answer but Apple has stated their displeasure for GCC on many occasions and declared it a deprecated technology.

Comment: @BraveS You mean the switching the compiler one?  If you read the question, OP indicates that they tried that already and got errors.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is useless.  If I had the power, I'd remove it from the internets.

Comment: @wallacer You got a better one? ;)  Apparently OP was ok with it since they accepted it...

Comment: @borrrden, (+) well done! all of those who voted to the other answer didn't read the question :)  (still the other answer is the one that helped me...)

Comment: @Yossi Indeed, the other answer is helpful to 99% of people, however the person who asked this question is one of the other 1% haha.

Comment: You obviously have a lot of wisdom to share. Why stifle it with cynicism?

Comment: don't delete the answer please and also the conversation too. Because it is a good lesson for us .

Comment: @Spynet I have no intention to at this point (and so far I haven't been able to since it is accepted :p).  I think I even got a medal for having so a low voted accepted answer.

Comment: I hope you have mistaken me , even n number of down votes ( you didn't delete answer ), i really appreciate you are leaders for us. and also your the so glittering stars.

Answer (score 234):

Change your compiler for C/C++/Objective-C:

`Xcode > Target > Build Settings > Build Options > Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C`

Select `Default compiler (Apple LLVM x.y)`

Comment: 99 problems but a compiler ain't one

Comment: Default compiler (Apple LLVM x.y) in that x and y will be your Xcode LLVM version

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling from the command line (like I do when building GEOS and proj4) The following command will find the correct compiler for you and run it.

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos clang
```

Or use iphonesimulator instead of iphoneos if you want to build for the sim.

Comment: do you add GEOS and proj4 as compiled static library? In my project they are attached as source code